# AWS DMS how to deal with invalid timestamp

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-dms, amazon-aurora

I am moving data from a MySQL Aurora Db which contains timestamp such as `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`.
The target is a redshift cluster. The migration is failing because the invalid timestamps are not accepted by Redshift.

I cannot modify the source data. I cannot drop that column (most of the timestamps are valid)

I have tried to use a replace-prefix transformation to replace `"0000-00-00"` by `"1970-01-01"`. It doesn't work because DMS is trying to load the data first and process them after.

How can I import the data ?

Comment: set up the target table with a varchar timestamp column.

Comment: you mean, I should change the strategy to TRUNCATE_BEFORE_LOAD (instead of DROP_AND_CREATE) and create the tables myself ? I will try it.

Comment: Correct - also you can set acceptanydate=true in the redshift target endpoint. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html#CHAP_Target.Redshift.ConnectionAttrib